# How to add (merge) multiple images in one directory

Tags: python, opencv, os.path

I have two types (A and B) of images in one directory and I want to add them together (not concatenate) them like this:

> *A1.jpeg + B1.jpeg = Merged1.jpeg 
>
> A2.jpeg + B2.jpeg = Merged2.jpeg 
>
>       **...**
>
> AN.jpeg + BN.jpeg = MergedN.jpeg*

I don't know how to customize my code so it would work for the whole directory:

```
import cv2
import os

for i,filenames in os.walk('.'):
    A1 = cv2.imread('A1.jpeg',0)
    B1 = cv2.imread('B1.jpeg',0)
    image = cv2.add([A1,B1])
    filename = ('Merged' + {i} + '.jpeg')
    cv2.imwrite(filename, image)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

### EDIT:

I added counter in for loop, because you cannot define for loop in the way I did before.

```
import cv2
import os

i=0

for filenames in os.walk('.'):
    i = i + 1
    A = "A" + str(i) + ".jpeg"
    B = "B" + str(i) + ".jpeg"
    Ai = cv2.imread(A,0)
    Bi = cv2.imread(B,0)
    image = cv2.add([Ai,Bi])
    filename = ('Merged' + str(i) + '.jpeg')
    cv2.imwrite(filename, image)
```

But it only adds A1 and B1. Is this a wrong way to count in for loop?

Comment: Regarding your edit, check what A and B are by printing. Even If cv2 doesn’t find a file, it remains silent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
import glob
import cv2

number_of_images = 750

for a_file in glob.glob('./A*'):
    for i in range(1,number_of_images):
        A = "A" + str(i) + ".jpeg"
        B = "B" + str(i) + ".jpeg"
        A1 = cv2.imread(A,0)
        B1 = cv2.imread(B,0)
        image = cv2.add([A1,B1])
        filename = ('Merged' + str(i) + '.jpeg')
        cv2.imwrite(filename, image)
        print(i)
    if i==number_of_images-1:
        break
```

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: You don’t even need to run glob if you have 750 as the number of all images. You are not using the variable a_file later in the loop. Right @reznik ? Run the loop using 750 i.e. Just the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` for that it will be easier i think

```py
import glob
for i, a_file in enumerate(glob.glob('./A*')):
    A = cv2.imread(a_file,0)
    B = cv2.imread(a_file.replace('A', 'B'),0)
    image = cv2.add([A,B])
    filename = ('Merged' + {i} + '.jpeg')
    cv2.imwrite(filename, image)
```

Comment: How do you define {i} in glob?

Comment: I am on mobile, but does enumerate return two things? One for i and one for a_file ? I think you forgot to repeat the glob for file name list.

Comment: @ankii enumrate takes an interable, and return the index, and the value it self in the right order in the iterable

Answer (score 0):

Just change the filename in `imread` with a custom variable which you can use `i` in.

```
A = "A" + str(i) + ".jpeg"
B = "B" + str(i) + ".jpeg"
Ai = cv2.imread(A,0)
Bi = cv2.imread(B,0)
```

I assumed that `i` is a number.

Comment: I get an error:
    
for i,filenames in os.walk('.'):

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Do you maybe know how to define i in os.walk()?

Comment: You can count the list os.walk returns and use range (count) for i to pick numbers from.